# Peoples Dictionary?

Tags: windows

I need some sort of software or website where I can story details about people, I need to sort of create a whole profile of certain people, a sort of private investigators workspace where when you find out something new about that person you can add to it and its all in 1 place for when you need to know.

Comment: Depending on the type of details you want to store, there may be different solutions. If the information is short, and you need to store the same information for lots of people, try Excel. Use a new row for each person, and columns for different features about those people. Another approach is to use a new row for each person and each cell for information about that person (so the same column may contain different types of info for different people)

If the info is complicated, too much for and Excel cell, maybe a database program will help.

Comment: As you have phrased your question, you could well use a Mind Map, such as [FreeMind](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). However, I suspect that you will want to search that data, not just look at it, so you need a specialized app - maybe look at one for managing friends?    Try searching on https://sourceforge.net/or GitHub

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [personal wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_wiki) for this project. I've been using [Zim](http://zim-wiki.org/) for general note-taking, but it could definitely be used for making and organizing notes about people.